# Given the system is working, the probability that component 2 is working is

Tags: probability

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8ZkV.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3wNz.png)

Consider the system below comprised of three components. The system is working if the is a path from left to right through working components. The components fail independently of one another with probability 0.3.
Given the system is working, the probability that component 2 is working is

Comment: Could you give more details for your question? For example, could you provide your attempts to your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: full question is in the image

Comment: @Community Is your comment addressing the failure of the OP to put the diagram in the question, rather than in an image linked to? If so the comment did not say that. Because a look at the image, along with the text in the question, makes it perfectly clear what OP is asking.